# Where clasue being partially ignored in update statement

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have this query I use on a clients side to create a search field from a few tables.

```
update xcart.xcart_products_lng_en
left join xcart.xcart_products on xcart.xcart_products.productid = xcart.xcart_products_lng_en.productid
left join xcart.xcart_extra_field_values on xcart.xcart_extra_field_values.productid = xcart.xcart_products.productid 

 set xcart.xcart_products_lng_en.keywords =  CONCAT(product , " ", productcode, " ",
        (select group_concat(xcart.xcart_extra_field_values.value 
        order by `xcart`.`xcart_extra_field_values`.`productid` 
        separator " ") 
    from xcart.xcart_extra_field_values 
    where xcart.xcart_extra_field_values.productid = xcart.xcart_products_lng_en.productid )) 
where value is not null or value not like ''
```

This works as expected but it's too loose, when It gets too many values, so I added

```
    fieldid != 11 or fieldid != 10 or fieldid != 12 or fieldid != 18 or fieldid != 19 or
fieldid != 20
    or fieldid != 15 or fieldid != 3 or fieldid != 16
```

but this gets ignored. Is there something I blatantly missed?

Comment: Have you ever heard of `NOT IN` ?

Comment: How would NOT IN work in this? I've discovered it recently, and I'm not completely sure of how it works yet.

Comment: `WHERE fieldid NOT IN (11, 10, 12, 18, 19, 20, 15, 3, 16)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `and`.

```
where value is not null or value not like ''
```

This will not filter out anything because any value will pass one side of the `or` or the other.  A `null` value will pass the right hand side because it is not like `''`, and `''` will pass the left hand side because it is not null.